# Output tab character on terminal window

Tags: bash, terminal, clipboard

How do I output a tab character (ASCII hex 0x09) on the terminal window ?

In all my experiments the tab character is changed to spaces when it appears on the terminal. E.g.

```
$ echo -e "xx\t\tyy"
xx              yy
```

which is not want I want since the space between `xx` and `yy` is filled with 14 spaces and not 2 tab characters. I tried `stty tab0`, `stty tab1`, `stty tab2` and `stty tab3`, but all gives the same result.

I am using GNOME Terminal 2.16.0 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.9.

Background:
I want to mouse-select the text on the terminal and paste into Excel. When I do this from Emacs (with 0x09 tabs between the fields) the fields end up in different columns. I like this, and want the same behavior when copy-pasting from the terminal. However, at present all the fields end up as one string in the first column. When I have spaces (0x20) between fields in Emacs, the behavior is the same as when copy-pasting from the terminal.

Comment: Could you please specify your OS and terminal emulator application?

Comment: xclip may be useful as in printf|xclip

Comment: In the first version of this question I by mistake wrote `echo -t` where it of course should have been `echo -e`. Some answers & comments below thus took me too literally. Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tab is not a printable character. Tab is a control character that usually advances the cursor (but not at the end of line), leaving the characters that it's jumping through unchanged.

`gnome-terminal` (and other `vte`-based emulators) have a special hack that it tries to preserve tabs for copy-paste purposes, however, it still loses them at a soft linebreak. Other emulators might also have such a hack, but typically they don't.

See also the conversation at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769316.

Comment: So are you saying that it should work for me as long as the tabs are not at the end ?

Comment: In terminals based on a recent enough VTE: yes. GNOME Terminal 2.16 might be a bit too old for this, though.

Comment: GNOME 2.16 was released in Sep 2006. The "smart tab" feature of VTE was implemented in Nov 2007. May I kindly recommend you to upgrade your systems to something reasonably recent? :)

Comment: I have just issued a ticket to IT. If this fixes my issue you deserve a big upvote. However, in that case your answer is confusing. It should start with the sentence "Use gnome-terminal 3.xx".

Comment: I'm not going to track down the very exact version where this appeared (some 2.22-ish perhaps), let alone it's not even gnome-terminal itself rather than vte that matters. I silently assume in all my answers I give on this site that the system being used is a sanely recent one, I go into version-dependent details if the change occurred no more than 2-3 years ago. For such an extreme as this one the comments clarify it.

Comment: Enjoy http://superuser.com/a/711019/38062  (-:

Answer (score 5):

If you use

```
printf "xx\t\tyy"
```

that should expand to a real tab-character.  The behavior of `echo` in regard to `bash` has been erratic.  I tested `bash` on my Debian 7, and found that neither `echo -t` nor `/bin/echo -t` gave a tab, while `printf` did (redirecting the output to a file to be sure).  Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -t "xx\t\tyy"
echo done
/bin/echo -t "xx\t\tyy"
echo done
echo "xx\t\tyy"
echo done
/bin/echo "xx\t\tyy"
echo done
printf "xx\t\tyy"
echo done
```

and output *to* the terminal:

```
-t xx\t\tyy
done
-t xx\t\tyy
done
xx\t\tyy
done
xx\t\tyy
done
xx              yydone
```

That's distinct from the additional problem of putting characters *on* the terminal screen.  As a rule, most terminals only have *spaces* selectable for cut/paste (irregardless of whether you print a tab or not). For that —

- [Is it possible to select tabs as tabs with mouse in urxvt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47578/is-it-possible-to-select-tabs-as-tabs-with-mouse-in-urxvt/321321#321321)

Comment: Yes you right: `echo -t "xx\t\tyy" | hexdump` shows wierd stuff whereas `printf "xx\t\tyy" | hexdump` shows the 0x09 tab character. However still get spaces on the terminal.

Comment: My comment above is junk. When I use the proper `echo -e` the results from `echo` and `printf` piped to `hexdump` are identical. The problem is my old `gnome-terminal` version 2.16.0 as another answers points out.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a tanget, but if all you want is to get the output into your clipboard so you can paste that into Excel, you can try using something like xclip. Note that you might have to install it. With xclip I can write something like this.

```
echo -e "xx\t\tyy" | xclip -selection c
```

It is now in my clipboard I can paste it into Excel. If echo doesn't work you can try printf instead.

If you don't want to type all of that every time you can create an alias instead.

```
alias xclip="xclip -selection c"
echo -e "xx\t\tyy" | xclip
```

And if nothing else you can always redirect the output you want to a file and just open it in a text-editor and copy what you need as tabs should stay as tabs in the file.

```
echo -e "xx\t\tyy" > tmpfile.txt
```